# How can I create a label/tooltip based on a list column of a data.frame

Tags: r, leaflet, tibble

I wish to create a constituency map of the UK in leaflet which when hovered over provides constituency name and detailed result.

The data is contained in a *tibble* with 2 columns:

1. constituency, which contains the name
2. result, which is a list column within each cell containing a data.frame including *candidate name*, *party*, *votes*, *%* and *order*.

I have included a sample of two constituencies below

```
df <- structure(list(constituency = c("Knowsley", "Bristol West"), 
result = list(structure(list(name = c("George Howarth", "James Spencer", 
"Neil Miney", "Carl Cashman", "Steve Baines"), party = c("Labour", 
"Conservative", "UKIP", "LD", "Green"), votes = c(47351L, 
5137L, 1285L, 1189L, 521L), pc = c(85.34, 9.26, 2.32, 2.14, 
0.94), order = 1:5), .Names = c("name", "party", "votes", 
"pc", "order"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), structure(list(name = c("Thangam Debbonaire", 
"Annabel Tall", "Molly Scott Cato", "Stephen Williams", "Jodian Rodgers"
), party = c("Labour", "Conservative", "Green", "LD", "Money Free Party"
), votes = c(47213L, 9877L, 9216L, 5201L, 101L), pc = c(65.93, 
13.79, 12.87, 7.26, 0.14), order = 1:5), .Names = c("name", 
"party", "votes", "pc", "order"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")))), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .Names = c("constituency", "result"))
```

If I just wanted the constituency in the label, I would have coded like this that I could apply to the leaflet output:

```
labels <- sprintf(
              df$constituency
          ) %>% lapply(htmltools::HTML)
```

But I wish to add in the *result* details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How bout this?

```
labels = lapply(1:length(df$result), function(i) {
  tmp = format(df$result[[i]])
  tmp = tmp[3:length(tmp)]
  tmp[1] = df$constituency[i]
  htmltools::HTML(paste(tmp, collapse = "<br>"))
})
```